# Write to app.config in .Net 3.5?

Tags: winforms, .net-3.5

I need to be able to write to the app.config file in my .Net 3.5 Windows app to store some system settings?

I can read from the file but I can't write to it??

Everything I have found is for 2.0 and doesn't look to be the same for 3.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET 2.0 is part of .NET 3.5

So just use what you found for .NET 2.0, or have a look at: [Read/Write App.config with .NET 2.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810043157/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/akraus1/articles/64871.aspx)

Also see SO answer: [Update app.config system.net setting at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980440/update-app-config-system-net-setting-at-runtime)