# app.config in .Net3.5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, app-config

I'm not able to write to the App.conf in .Net3.5.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218520/write-to-app-config-in-net-3-5) question it goes like in .Net2.0, but it doesn't work. I can read from the config like this:

```
var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ApplicationConstants.CisConnectionStringName].ConnectionString
```

But it's impossible for me to write in that file, because the compiler says it's not possible because of the security level.

I googled for several hours but found no solution. I hope you can help.

Thx

**Edit:**

I tried different Ways:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ApplicationConstants.CisConnectionStringName].ConnectionString = "string";
```

also...

```
 Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
NetSectionGroup netSectionGroup = config.GetSectionGroup("system.net") as NetSectionGroup;
netSectionGroup.Settings.HttpWebRequest.UseUnsafeHeaderParsing = true;                      
config.SaveAs(@"C:\ProgramData\test.config", ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", @"C:\ProgramData\test.config");
```

also...

```
string exePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase.Substring(0, System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase.LastIndexOf('/'));
        var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath);
...
```

(Examples not valid for the given Path, as I tested it they where ;-))

But nothing worked. The config file is in the same directory as the .exe (currently "C:\Users\MyUser\SVN\CIS\Assemblies")

Comment: Can you show us how you try to write the settings? Where are your config file located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
 System.Configuration.Configuration config =ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        config.AppSettings.Settings["oldPlace"].Value = "3";     
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```