# Updating a value in a local app.config

Tags: c#, app-config

I've got an exe that reads some values from its local `app.config` file:

```
TargetDate = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ThresholdDate");

// and try to update with the current date
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("ThresholdDate", "2011-09-01");
```

I thought it worked once, but am not seeing the `app.config` getting updated at all now.

Comment: is this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980440/update-app-config-system-net-setting-at-runtime

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try something like this:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
//change the config value
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

I am not sure abt the syntax for changing the config value but I have done an `Add` before and I know you can do a remove so I guess you could do a combination of remove and add like this:

```
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("ThresholdDate");
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("ThresholdDate", "2011-09-01");
```

Comment: what is the C# syntax for changing the config value?

Comment: did you do a save and refresh after that?

Comment: config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);       ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

Comment: I can save the value,and turn right around and extract the value right away, but it does not persist after application ends execution

Comment: looks like it is being changed in the <appname>.vshost.exe.config instead of app.config and the value is not persisted after execution

Comment: So am I correct in the assumption that you cannot change and persist a value in your app.config for use next time you run the app?

Answer (score 2):

Looking here: [How to change App.config file run time using C#](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/how-to-change-appconfig-file-run-time-using-c/) is the answer - while running in the visual studio IDE, you will not see the values persisted in the /bin/appname.exe.config.  You actually have to go into the bin directory and run the exe.

So this code actually works, just not in debug mode:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

config.AppSettings.Settings["ThresholdDate"].Value = Convert.ToString(testdate);
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Comment: if it solved your issue, you should mark this as your accepted answer (48hrs timer should be expired now)

Answer (score -1):

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

config.AppSettings.Settings["ThresholdDate"].Value = Convert.ToString(testdate);
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

this will work only while your not in debuging mode. try to run yung code in /debug/appName.exe and the you will se the changes in appName.exe.config

cheers!