# exceuting some statments only once (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

I have a question , Can I execute statements only once at first application execution ? can it be done without registery keys or installer?

Comment: A code example would help a lot

Comment: how would you know its the first execution

Comment: If not executed then Execute...

Comment: Basically, you need to store some variable OUTSIDE of your program that tells the program whether or not to execute those statements. The simplest way would be to, for example, include a text file with your executable that basically only says `RunMe=True`, say, and change it after those statements run the first time to `RunMe=False`

Comment: Perhaps you could create a "dummy" file to indicate that your application has been executed. Then, simply check if that file exists, or not, when your application starts.

Answer (score 2):

Simply store a value in the App.Config

```
<appSettings>
<add key="HasExecuted" value ="0"/>
```

In code:

```
If Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("HasExecuted")) = False Then
'Do something only once
End If
```

Here is a guide to saving/updating the AppConfig: [Update app.config system.net setting at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980440/update-app-config-system-net-setting-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not explain why you don't want to/can use any "common" method for storing state parameters for your application, I will assume that it's for anti-piracy purposes.

---

I guess it all depends to the depths you want to go.

So, here's something I've done on several commercial applications I've developed (mainly, but not limited, to prevent piracy):

- Encrypt the original executable using your own proprietary algorithm (perhaps, not necessary in your situation)
- Create a launcher application which can decrypt and execute your application
- Implement, into the launcher, a mechanism to modify some areas of the original application, that do not affect its execution (hint: meta-data/resources/etc...)
- Save the modified code

Consequent executions of the program can then easily detect "parameters/values/settings" by "detecting" such changes.

Again, this is a quite complex and rather obscure way to store start-up arguments (or states) for an application, but again, depending on what you are looking for, this is a quite secure and effective method.

---

Here's a sample demonstrating the "basics" of this method: [HiddenParams](http://xfx.net/stackoverflow/HiddenParams.zip)